# Difference pixels (font-size) same browser on two computers

Tags: css, firefox

In Firefox I notice differences between 2 computers in how pixel are display (same version of Firefox-28 same Windows 7)

in one computer this CSS doesn't break line

```
.mainMenu ul li {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 52px;
}
```

in the other computer this cause the line to break and the right CSS is

```
.mainMenu ul li {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 47px;
}
```

What can be the problem that cause different computers with same operating system and same browser version to result in 2 different way?

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/QPxNS/1/

I am adding 2 screenshot from different computers
[image]

[image]

Thanks
Baaroz

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle with the code? thank you

Comment: why does the margin-right value differ? Is there any other differences between the code on each machine? jsfiddle will help

Comment: Please post the code to create a full example ... HTML and CSS. A jsFiddle would be helpful as well.

Comment: ok I will try to Restore the problem with jsFiddle

Comment: what is the screen width in pixels on each machine? looking at the screen shots I suspect this could be the cause. I have not had  time to check the fiddle yet

Comment: Feels like a "zooming" issue.

Comment: zoom both 100%,the container is 970px center so I don't think it's screen width issue

Comment: Besides browser zoom setting (make sure to hit `Ctrl+0` for `Normal` setting in Firefox, there's also OS zooming, that can even be different in different user accounts on Win 7. Have a look at `Control Panel -> Display-> Change Text Size`, see also http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-defaults-text-size-to-medium-125-how-can/46ec13bc-4157-4aca-a896-f1a99bdf5f55 and https://superuser.com/questions/577516/how-to-change-the-default-system-dpi

Comment: @baaroz -- did my comment answer your question?